# Lookahead regex in Ruby returns `nil` on irb

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have input:

```
s = "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\" val = \"1234\">"
```

I want to fetch `'HelloWorld'` and `'1234'`.

I am using this regex expression

```
(?<=\")+[a-zA-Z0-9]*+(?=\\)
```

[On rubular](http://rubular.com/r/QTwFbb8g92), it gives the expected result, but on irb, it returns `nil`:

```
s.scan(/(?<=\")+[a-zA-Z0-9]*+(?=\\)/) # => []
```

Why this is happening can anybody explain ? what I am missing

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa

please checkout this url http://rubular.com/r/QTwFbb8g92
Regex that I have mentioned above is giving prefect result on rubular but on my local irb it returning an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\" val = \"1234\">"
```

the string value is:

```
<tag1 value = "HelloWorld" val = "1234">
```

It can be easily checked by executing e. g. `puts s`. You see the backslashes there because the string in ruby might be declared using double quotes and in this case the double quotes inside string are to be escaped with backslashes. Other ways to declare the same string in ruby are:

```
s = '<tag1 value = "HelloWorld" val = "1234">'
s = %|<tag1 value = "HelloWorld" val = "1234">|
s = <<STR
<tag1 value = "HelloWorld" val = "1234">
STR
```

neither requires escaping double quotes. If you have copied the string as it was displayed in IRB to rubular, with escaping backslashes, you’ve matched another string.

That said, since there are no backslashes in the original string, nothing was matched in ruby. There are other glitches with the regexp you’ve used.

Here is the most careful version of the regexp:

```
s.scan /(?<=")\w+(?=")/
#⇒ ["HelloWorld", "1234"]
```

Comment: yeah, I miss understood those backslashes thanks for that. '\w' represent a word  ?

Comment: This is how I am fetching attribute name from the same string is it right approach ?
http://rubular.com/r/xH3WHgu3Nw

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/hajMxQK0di ⇒ yours was a bit superfluous. `\w` is a “word symbol”: a letter, a digit or an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the regex slightly to wrap around the last `\"` instead. I suspect it has to do with \ being the Ruby escape character.

```
> "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\" val = \"1234\">".scan(/(?<=\")+[a-zA-Z0-9]*+(?=\")/)
#=> ["HelloWorld", "1234"]
```

Comment: Thanks missed that one